# How to send notification to a particular device given that we have its registration token?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification using device id to a particular device. I am trying to send notification to parent whenever his/her child crosses defined geofence. So basically its like having Device to device communication.

I have seen many examples of FCM but they are sending the notification using Firebase console. Also they don't have any particular method to send notification to the desired Device Id.
Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See the Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation on sending a message to a specific device: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices

Answer (score 0):

You will need a backend to handle sending notification from device to another device, first register the child's token and father's token to the backend via a request then whenever the notification needs to be sent, send a request to the backend and the backend will trigger send the father the notification.